# Tiling and Packing a board using Hexominoes with javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm tiling and packing 15 x 15 board with hexomino figures. To fill a 15 x 15 rectangle with a hexomino figure, I have to use all of the 35 hexominoes, one duplicate figure, and a 3x3 square.
So, I created 3x3 square and made one duplicate figure randomly. 
When I tested on a small board like 9 X 15, I can quickly find the answer as you can see.

Every hexomino has its own key 0 to 36 and 'mark' variable to check if it's used.

[image]

However, the problem is that it takes too long to find the 15 x 15 solution. To test this, I slept with the script turned on, but I couldn't get the result.
I double-checked all the hexomino coordinates, so I think this algorithm is just not good.

Therefore, I used Python with another method, and I could find the answer 
[image]

This is my js code having a problem.

```
  colors = [
    "#EEAAAA", "#DDBB99", "#CCCC88", "#BBDD99", "#AAEEAA", "#99DDBB", "#B22222",
    "#88CCCC", "#99BBDD", "#AAAAEE", "#BB99DD", "#CC88CC", "#DD99BB", "#663399",
    "#C0C0C0" ,"#4682B4", "#D2B48C", "#2E8B57", "#FF0000", "#B0E0E6", "#DB7093",
    "#FFDAB9",   "green", "#EEE8AA",    "gray", "#191970", "#00FA9A", "#48D1CC",
    "#C71585", "#800000", "#FFA07A",  "orange",  "yellow", "#2F4F4F", "#FF8C00",
    "#556B2F", "white"

  ]; // Colors to distinguish hexomino

function setup() { 
  createCanvas(2500, 2500);

  puzzle = new Puzzle();
  puzzle.run(9,15);

} 

function draw() { 
  paint(puzzle);
}

function Square(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.move = function(row, column) {
    return new Square(this.x + column, this.y + row);
  };
  this.check = function(width, height) {
    if (this.x < 0 || this.y < 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      if (this.x >= width || this.y >= height) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  };
}

function Hexomino(key, squares) {
  this.key = key;
  this.squares = squares.map(function(square) {
    return new Square(square[0], square[1]);
  });
  this.move = function(row, column) {
    var hexo = new Hexomino(this.key, []);
    hexo.squares = this.squares.map(function(square) {
      return square.move(row, column);
    });
    return hexo;
  };
}

//Hexominoes Coordinates
function Hexominos() {
  this.shapes = [
    [ // #0 = 1 figure , 9 cells
      new Hexomino( 0, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]),
    ],

    [ // #1 = 2
      new Hexomino( 1, [[0,0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0,4], [0,5]]),
      new Hexomino( 1, [[0,0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4,0], [5,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #2 = 8
      new Hexomino( 2, [[0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3, 1], [4,1], [4,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 2, [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [1, 2], [1,3], [1,4]]),
      new Hexomino( 2, [[0,1], [0,0], [1,0], [2, 0], [3,0], [4,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 2, [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0, 3], [0,4], [1,4]]),

      new Hexomino( 2, [[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [4,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 2, [[0,4], [1,4], [1,3], [1,2], [1,1], [1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 2, [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [4,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 2, [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], [1,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #3 = 8
      new Hexomino( 3, [[0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3,1],[3,0],[4,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 3, [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3],[1,3],[0,4]]),
      new Hexomino( 3, [[0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]),
      new Hexomino( 3, [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [2,0],[3,0],[4,0]]),

      new Hexomino( 3, [[0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [2,1],[3,1],[4,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 3, [[0,3], [1,3], [1,4], [1,2],[1,1],[1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 3, [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0],[3,1],[4,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 3, [[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [0,2],[0,3],[0,4]]),

    ],

    [ // #4 = 4
      new Hexomino( 4, [[0,1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2,0], [3,1], [4,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 4, [[0,0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2,1], [3,0], [4,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 4, [[0,2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1,4], [1,1], [1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 4, [[0,0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1,2], [0,3], [0,4]]),
    ],

    [ // #5 = 8
      new Hexomino( 5, [[0,1], [1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[3,0],[4,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 5, [[0,1], [1,1],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 5, [[0,0], [0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,3],[1,4]]),
      new Hexomino( 5, [[0,0], [0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]),

      new Hexomino( 5, [[0,0], [1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 5, [[0,0], [1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[3,1],[4,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 5, [[0,4], [0,3],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 5, [[0,4], [0,3],[0,2],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #6 = 8
      new Hexomino( 6, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 6, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 6, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 6, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 6, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 6, [[0,2],[0,3],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 6, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 6, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,0],[1,1]]),
    ],

    [ // #7 = 8
      new Hexomino( 7, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,1],[3,1],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 7, [[0,0],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 7, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 7, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[1,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 7, [[0,0],[2,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 7, [[0,1],[0,3],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 7, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[1,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 7, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,0],[1,2]]),
    ],
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ // #8 = 4
      new Hexomino( 8, [[0,0],[3,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 8, [[0,0],[0,3],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 8, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 8, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,0],[1,3]]),
    ],

    [ // #9 = 4
      new Hexomino( 9, [[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 9, [[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 9, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[1,1],[2,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 9, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[1,2]]),
    ],

    [ // #10 = 8
      new Hexomino( 10, [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[3,1],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 10, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 10, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 10, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,3],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 10, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]]),  
      new Hexomino( 10, [[0,3],[1,3],[2,3],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 10, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 10, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,0],[2,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #11 = 8
      new Hexomino( 11, [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 11, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 11, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 11, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[2,2]]),

      new Hexomino( 11, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,2],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 11, [[0,2],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 11, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[2,1],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 11, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[2,1]]),
    ],

    [ // #12 = 4
      new Hexomino( 12, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[3,2],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 12, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 12, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 12, [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[0,3],[2,3]]),
    ],

    [ // #13 = 8
      new Hexomino( 13, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[3,1],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 13, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 13, [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 13, [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[0,2],[1,3],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 13, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 13, [[0,3],[1,3],[1,2],[2,2],[1,1],[1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 13, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[3,1],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 13, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0],[1,2],[1,3]]),
    ],

    [ // #14 = 8
      new Hexomino( 14, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[3,1],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 14, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[1,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 14, [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 14, [[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 14, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 14, [[0,3],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1],[1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 14, [[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 14, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0]]),
    ],

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ // #15 = 4
      new Hexomino( 15, [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 15, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 15, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 15, [[0,3],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #16 = 4
      new Hexomino( 16, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,0],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 16, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2]]),

      new Hexomino( 16, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,1],[2,2],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 16, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[1,1],[2,1],[1,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #17 = 4
      new Hexomino( 17, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[2,2],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 17, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 17, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,3],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 17, [[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[1,3]]),
    ],

    [ // #18 = 8
      new Hexomino( 18, [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 18, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 18, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 18, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2]]),

      new Hexomino( 18, [[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 18, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 18, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1],[3,1],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 18, [[1,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[2,1]]),
    ],

    [ // #19 = 8
      new Hexomino( 19, [[0,0],[2,0],[3,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 19, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[0,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 19, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 19, [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3]]),

      new Hexomino (19, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino (19, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[0,2],[0,3]]),
      new Hexomino (19, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino (19, [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,3],[1,1],[1,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #20 = 4
      new Hexomino( 20, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 20, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]),

      new Hexomino( 20, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 20, [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4]]),
    ],

    [ // #21 = 4 figures, set to 12 cells (duplicate)
      // new Hexomino( 21, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      // new Hexomino( 21, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]]),

      // new Hexomino( 21, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      // new Hexomino( 21, [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]),

      new Hexomino( 21, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 21, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1]]),

      new Hexomino( 21, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 21, [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[0,6],[1,5],[1,4],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0]]),
    ],

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ // #22 = 2
      new Hexomino( 22, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 22, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]),
    ],

    [ // #23 = 8
      new Hexomino( 23, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 23, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[1,2],[1,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 23, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 23, [[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 23, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 23, [[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[2,2],[1,1],[1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 23, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[2,2],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 23, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[1,2],[1,3]]),
    ],

    [ // #24 = 8
      new Hexomino( 24, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[1,0],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 24, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[2,0],[1,1],[1,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 24, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 24, [[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]]),

      new Hexomino( 24, [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[0,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 24, [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 24, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 24, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]]),
    ],

    [ // #25 = 8
      new Hexomino( 25, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 25, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[1,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 25, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[3,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 25, [[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 25, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 25, [[0,3],[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1],[1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 25, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,1],[2,2],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 25, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #26 = 8
      new Hexomino( 26, [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 26, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 26, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 26, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 26, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 26, [[0,3],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 26, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 26, [[0,3],[0,2],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #27 = 8
      new Hexomino( 27, [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[3,1],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 27, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 27, [[0,2],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 27, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 27, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 27, [[0,3],[1,3],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 27, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1],[3,1],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 27, [[0,3],[0,2],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #28 = 8
      new Hexomino( 28, [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0],[1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 28, [[0,1],[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 28, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,0],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 28, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1]]),

      new Hexomino( 28, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[1,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 28, [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 28, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[1,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 28, [[0,2],[0,1],[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1]]),
    ],

    [ // #29 = 8
      new Hexomino( 29, [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 29, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 29, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[1,1],[1,2],[0,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 29, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2]]),

      new Hexomino( 29, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[0,2],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 29, [[0,2],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 29, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 29, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #30 = 4
      new Hexomino( 30, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0],[1,2],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 30, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 30, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[1,2],[0,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 30, [[0,2],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,1],[2,2]]),
    ],

    [ // #31 = 8
      new Hexomino( 31, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 31, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,3]]),
      new Hexomino( 31, [[0,2],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 31, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 31, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 31, [[0,3],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 31, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 31, [[0,3],[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0]]),

    ],

    [ // #32 = 4
      new Hexomino( 32, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 32, [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 32, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 32, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2]]),
    ],

    [ // #33 = 4
      new Hexomino( 33, [[0,2],[0,1],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 33, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[1,0],[2,1],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 33, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[1,0],[2,0],[1,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 33, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[1,2]]),
    ],

    [ // #34 = 8
      new Hexomino( 34, [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 34, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[1,2],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 34, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],[2,1],[2,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 34, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2]]),

      new Hexomino( 34, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 34, [[0,2],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1]]),
      new Hexomino( 34, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 34, [[0,2],[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,0]]),
    ],

    [ // #35 = 4
      new Hexomino( 35, [[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[3,0]]),
      new Hexomino( 35, [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,3]]),

      new Hexomino( 35, [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[3,2]]),
      new Hexomino( 35, [[0,3],[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0]]),
    ]
    // [ // #36 = any dulicate cell
    //   new Hexomino( 36, [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]),
    //   new Hexomino( 36, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]]),

    //   new Hexomino( 36, [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]),
    //   new Hexomino( 36, [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]])
    // ],
  ];
  this.rectangle = [];
  this.enumerator = function(row, column, width, height) {
    return this.shapes.map(function(a) {
      return a.map(function(b) {
        return b.move(row, column);
      }).filter(function(c) {
        return c.squares.every(function(d) {
          return d.check(width, height);
        });
      });
    });
  };
  this.initialize = function(width, height) {
    var row, column;
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
      this.rectangle[row] = [];
      for (column = 0; column < width; column++) {
        this.rectangle[row][column] = 
          this.enumerator(row, column, width, height);
      }
    }
  };
}

function State(rectangle, mask, count) {
  this.rectangle = rectangle;
  this.mask = mask;
  this.count = count;
  this.shapes = [];
  this.index = -1;
  this.select = function() {
    var row, column;
    for (row = 0; row < this.rectangle.length; row++) {
      for (column = 0; column < this.rectangle[row].length; column++) {
        if (this.rectangle[row][column] === false) {
          return new Square(column, row);
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
  this.add = function(rectangle) {
    var square, shapes;
    square = this.select();
    if (square != null) {
      shapes = rectangle[square.y][square.x];
      this.mask.forEach(function(value, index) {
        if (value === false) {
          shapes[index].forEach(function(shape) {
            this.shapes.push(shape);
          }, this);
        }
      }, this);
    }
  };
  this.next = function() {
    this.index = this.index + 1;
    return this.index < this.shapes.length;
  };
  this.fit = function() {
    var shape;
    shape = this.shapes[this.index];
    return shape.squares.every(function(square) {
      return this.rectangle[square.y][square.x] === false;
    }, this);
  };
  this.copy = function() {
    var rectangle, shape, mask, count;
    rectangle = this.rectangle.map(function(row) {
      return row.slice();
    });
    shape = this.shapes[this.index];
    shape.squares.forEach(function(square) {
      rectangle[square.y][square.x] = true;
    });
    mask = this.mask.slice();
    mask[shape.key] = true;

// Until Count equals to 225 (15 x 15 = 225 cells)
    if(shape.key == 0){
      count = this.count + 9;
    }
    else if (shape.key == 21){
      count = this.count + 12;
    }
    else{
      count = this.count + 6;
    }

    return new State(rectangle, mask, count);
  };
}

function Puzzle() {
  this.stack = [];
  this.first = function(width, height) {
    var rectangle, row, column, mask;
    rectangle = [];
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
      rectangle[row] = [];
      for (column = 0; column < width; column++) {
        rectangle[row][column] = false;
      }
    }
    mask = [
      false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
      false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
      false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
      false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
      false, false, false, false, false, false, false
    ];
    return new State(rectangle, mask, 0);
  };
  this.run = function(width, height) {
    var hexo, state, count;
    hexo = new Hexominos();
    hexo.initialize(width, height);
    state = this.first(width, height);
    state.add(hexo.rectangle);
    this.stack.push(state);
    count = width * height;
    while (this.stack.length > 0) {
      state = this.stack.pop();
      if (state.count == count) {
        break;
      }
      while (state.next()) {
        if (state.fit()) {
          this.stack.push(state);
          state = state.copy();
          state.add(hexo.rectangle);
          this.stack.push(state);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  };
}


function paint(puzzle) {


  puzzle.stack.forEach(async function(state) {
    var shape;
    shape = state.shapes[state.index];
    fill(colors[shape.key])      
    shape.squares.forEach(async function(square) {
      rect(square.x * 25, square.y * 25, 25, 25);
    });
  });
}
```

My question is how I can improve this code's speed and modify it to get a solution. Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to improve the speed, you should try finding the bottleneck first by putting [`console.time` and `console.timeEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) calls around your various functions. Usually there is one function that takes a long time to compute and by improving it your whole code will get significantly faster.

Comment: Also see the [post by Google regarding debugging runtime speed](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools), it's for Chrome, but it will apply to other browsers as well.

Comment: It's working somehow. Thank you!